# How does Magento 2 auto fill text fields using knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

Please let me know which JS file handle the auto fill functionality in product creation module? They auto fill the "SKU" field while typing in the "Product name" field. I have searched by "afterkeydown" property but couldn't find any.

I need this functionality for the configurable variation creation section as explained below

[image]

In the configurable variation creation section, I have edited the summary.js (extend it as summary-custom.js) to show the additional simple attributes.
Here we can see that for the "size 1" all the 8 simple attributes values should be same. For example if "Base color: Anthracite, size: 1" has "Height" => 1, then the "Base color: Blue Tones, size: 1"'s "Height" should be automatically filled by "1" as Magento had done for the "sku" field update when we type in the "Product name" field.

How can I do this? Can I use the "summary.js" to achieve this?

Here is my summary-custom.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/paging/paging',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/steps/summary'
], function (Component, $, ko, _, paging, summary) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            modules: {
                variationsComponent: '${ $.variationsComponent }',
                modalComponent: '${ $.modalComponent }'
            },
            notificationMessage: {
                text: null,
                error: null
            },
            gridExisting: [],
            gridNew: [],
            gridDeleted: [],
            variationsExisting: [],
            variationsNew: [],
            variationsDeleted: [],
            pagingExisting: paging({
                name: 'configurableWizard.pagingExisting',
                sizesConfig: {
                    component: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/paging/sizes',
                    name: 'configurableWizard.pagingExisting_sizes'
                }
            }),
            pagingNew: paging({
                name: 'configurableWizard.pagingNew',
                sizesConfig: {
                    component: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/paging/sizes',
                    name: 'configurableWizard.pagingNew_sizes'
                }
            }),
            pagingDeleted: paging({
                name: 'configurableWizard.pagingDeleted',
                sizesConfig: {
                    component: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/paging/sizes',
                    name: 'configurableWizard.pagingDeleted_sizes'
                }
            }),
            attributes: [],
            attributesName: [$.mage.__('Images'), $.mage.__('SKU'), $.mage.__('Quantity'), $.mage.__('Height'), $.mage.__('Lower length'), $.mage.__('Lower width'), $.mage.__('Planting depth'), $.mage.__('Planting length'), $.mage.__('Planting width'), $.mage.__('Upper length'), $.mage.__('Upper width'), $.mage.__('Price')],
            sections: [],
            gridTemplate: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/variations/steps/summary-grid'
        },
        initObservable: function () {
            var pagingObservables = {
                currentNew: ko.getObservable(this.pagingNew, 'current'),
                currentExisting: ko.getObservable(this.pagingExisting, 'current'),
                currentDeleted: ko.getObservable(this.pagingDeleted, 'current'),
                pageSizeNew: ko.getObservable(this.pagingNew, 'pageSize'),
                pageSizeExisting: ko.getObservable(this.pagingExisting, 'pageSize'),
                pageSizeDeleted: ko.getObservable(this.pagingDeleted, 'pageSize')
            };

            this._super().observe('gridExisting gridNew gridDeleted attributes sections');
            this.gridExisting.columns = ko.observableArray();
            this.gridNew.columns = ko.observableArray();
            this.gridDeleted.columns = ko.observableArray();

            _.each(pagingObservables, function (observable) {
                observable.subscribe(function () {
                    this.generateGrid();
                }, this);
            }, this);

            return this;
        },
        nextLabelText: $.mage.__('Generate Products'),
        variations: [],
        calculate: function (variations, getSectionValue) {
            var productSku = this.variationsComponent().getProductValue('sku'),
                productPrice = this.variationsComponent().getProductPrice(),
                productWeight = this.variationsComponent().getProductValue('weight'),
                variationsKeys = [],
                gridExisting = [],
                gridNew = [],
                gridDeleted = [];

            this.variations = [];
            _.each(variations, function (options) {
                var product, images, sku, quantity, price, size_height, size_lower_length, size_lower_width, size_planting_depth, size_planting_length, size_planting_width, size_upper_length, size_upper_width, variation,
                    productId = this.variationsComponent().getProductIdByOptions(options);

                size_height = '';
                size_lower_length = '';
                size_lower_width = '';
                size_planting_depth = '';
                size_planting_length = '';
                size_planting_width = '';
                size_upper_length = '';
                size_upper_width = '';

                if (productId) {
                    product = _.findWhere(this.variationsComponent().variations, {
                        productId: productId
                    });
                    console.log("here");
                    size_height = product.size_height;
                    size_lower_length = product.size_lower_length;
                    size_lower_width = product.size_lower_width;
                    size_planting_depth = product.size_planting_depth;
                    size_planting_length = product.size_planting_length;
                    size_planting_width = product.size_planting_width;
                    size_upper_length = product.size_upper_length;
                    size_upper_width = product.size_upper_width;
                }
                images = getSectionValue('images', options);
                sku = productSku + _.reduce(options, function (memo, option) {
                    return memo + '-' + option.label;
                }, '');
                quantity = getSectionValue('quantity', options);

                if (!quantity && productId) {
                    quantity = product.quantity;
                }
                price = getSectionValue('price', options);

                if (!price) {
                    price = productId ? product.price : productPrice;
                }

                if (productId && !images.file) {
                    images = product.images;
                }
                variation = {
                    options: options,
                    images: images,
                    sku: sku,
                    name: sku,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    price: price,
                    size_height: size_height,
                    size_lower_length: size_lower_length,
                    size_lower_width: size_lower_width,
                    size_planting_depth: size_planting_depth,
                    size_planting_length: size_planting_length,
                    size_planting_width: size_planting_width,
                    size_upper_length: size_upper_length,
                    size_upper_width: size_upper_width,
                    productId: productId,
                    weight: productWeight,
                    editable: true
                };

                if (productId) {
                    variation.sku = product.sku;
                    variation.weight = product.weight;
                    variation.name = product.name;
                    gridExisting.push(this.prepareRowForGrid(variation));
                } else {
                    gridNew.push(this.prepareRowForGrid(variation));
                }
                this.variations.push(variation);
                variationsKeys.push(this.variationsComponent().getVariationKey(options));
            }, this);

            _.each(_.omit(this.variationsComponent().productAttributesMap, variationsKeys), function (productId) {
                gridDeleted.push(this.prepareRowForGrid(
                    _.findWhere(this.variationsComponent().variations, {
                        productId: productId
                    })
                ));
            }.bind(this));

            this.variationsExisting = gridExisting;
            this.variationsNew = gridNew;
            this.variationsDeleted = gridDeleted;

        },
        generateGrid: function () {
            var pageExisting = this.pagingExisting.pageSize * this.pagingExisting.current,
                pageNew = this.pagingNew.pageSize * this.pagingNew.current,
                pageDeleted = this.pagingDeleted.pageSize * this.pagingDeleted.current;

            this.pagingExisting.totalRecords = this.variationsExisting.length;
            this.gridExisting(this.variationsExisting.slice(pageExisting - this.pagingExisting.pageSize, pageExisting));

            this.pagingNew.totalRecords = this.variationsNew.length;
            this.gridNew(this.variationsNew.slice(pageNew - this.pagingNew.pageSize, pageNew));

            this.pagingDeleted.totalRecords = this.variationsDeleted.length;
            this.gridDeleted(this.variationsDeleted.slice(pageDeleted - this.pagingDeleted.pageSize, pageDeleted));
        },
        prepareRowForGrid: function (variation) {
            var row = [];

            row.push(_.extend({
                images: []
            }, variation.images));
            row.push(variation.sku);
            row.push(variation.quantity);
            row.push(variation.size_height);
            row.push(variation.size_lower_length);
            row.push(variation.size_lower_width);
            row.push(variation.size_planting_depth);
            row.push(variation.size_planting_length);
            row.push(variation.size_planting_width);
            row.push(variation.size_upper_length);
            row.push(variation.size_upper_width);
            _.each(variation.options, function (option) {
                row.push(option.label);
            });
            row.push(this.variationsComponent().getCurrencySymbol() +  ' ' + variation.price);

            return row;
        },
        getGridTemplate: function () {
            return this.gridTemplate;
        },
        getGridId: function () {
            return _.uniqueId('grid_');
        },
        getColumnsName: function (attributes) {
            var columns = this.attributesName.slice(0);

            attributes.each(function (attribute, index) {
                columns.splice(11 + index, 0, attribute.label);
            }, this);

            return columns;
        },
        render: function (wizard) {
            this.wizard = wizard;
            this.sections(wizard.data.sections());
            this.attributes(wizard.data.attributes());
            this.gridNew([]);
            this.gridExisting([]);
            this.gridDeleted([]);
            this.gridExisting.columns(this.getColumnsName(this.wizard.data.attributes));
            this.gridNew.columns(this.getColumnsName(this.wizard.data.attributes));
            this.gridDeleted.columns(this.getColumnsName(this.variationsComponent().productAttributes));
            this.calculate(wizard.data.variations, wizard.data.sectionHelper);
            this.generateGrid();
        },
        force: function () {
            this.variationsComponent().render(this.variations, this.attributes());
            this.modalComponent().closeModal();
        },
        back: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because *they* doesn't use "afterkeydown" event directly. They use Knockout the [`value`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) binding and the `valueUpdate` as additional binding. It is under the hood. For developers it looks like property `valueUpdate` on field level.

In the [`DataProvider/../Modifier/General.php` file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php#L317) you can find that JavaScript component changed from the default. It is an `import-handler.js`, where new value for the property `valueUpdate` [is assigned](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/import-handler.js#L26).